# how to show multiple row data into in a row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

hi guys i am new to learn MySQL i have this table

```
f_id|c_file|e.name|operation|rate|c_no | qty|
 1    015    A      coping   0.30  1    1300
 2    015    A      coping   0.30  2    4567
 3    015    A      coping   0.30  3    1300
 4    015    A      coping   0.30  4    789
 5    015    A      coping   0.30  5    47
 6    015    B      cutting  0.30  1    568
 7    015    B      cutting  0.30  2    123
 8    015    B      cutting  0.30  3    8952
 9    015    B      cutting  0.30  1    456
 10   015    B      cutting  0.30  2    89
 11   015    B      cutting  0.30  3    78
```

now i want table like in this form of table 
table2

```
f_id|c_file|e.name|operation|c_no1|c_no2 |c_no3|c_no4|c_no5|total|rate|total*rate
 2     015  B       cutting 568     123   8952              9643  0.30 2892.9
 2     015  B       cutting 456     89    78                9643  0.30 2892.9
 total                      1024    212   9030
```

Comment: please put here what you tried

Comment: You can simple select multiple tables. `SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1, table2`

Comment: This is called pivot table and have been asked & answered many time here on SO.

Comment: The linked duplicate describes both static (number of additional fields is known in advance) and dynamic pivoting (number of fields is not known in advance) in MySQL.

Comment: can someone told me how to sum column wise total

Comment: If the number of columns is dynamic, you are best pivoting in client code.  See also [_Auto generate pivot SELECT_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot)

Comment: as i mention i am new in mysql can you give easy way to fulfill this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to do the pivoting and user variables to generate the sequence number.

```
set @fid := 0;

select @fid := @fid + 1 fid,
    c_file,
    e.name,
    operation,
    sum(case when c_no = 1 then qty end) c_no1,
    sum(case when c_no = 2 then qty end) c_no2,
    sum(case when c_no = 3 then qty end) c_no3,
    sum(case when c_no = 4 then qty end) c_no4,
    sum(case when c_no = 5 then qty end) c_no5,
    sum(qty) total,
    rate,
    sum(qty) * rate total_times_rate
from t
group by c_file,
    e.name,
    operation,
    rate
order by min(f_id);
```

Comment: thanks alot sir ,can you tell me one thing more that how to sum all the columns like(c_no1+c_no2+c_no3+c_no4+c_no5) please...

Comment: @user3602024 - Please see the edit

Comment: thanks again gurv sir....

Comment: sir this query is not working for adding the value of columns !! can you write again full query with sum

Comment: sir i have also edited the question sir kindly give the answer i know i am going too much worst but i have to ask

Comment: @user3602024 - Updated the answer for you

Comment: thanks sir alot .....